# Problematic third order term in saddle point method

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, asymptotics

When evaluating $$I \equiv \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\,e^{-f(x)}$$ using saddle point method we expand $f(x)$ as done [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14639/how-is-the-saddle-point-approximation-used-in-physics/14641#14641) but my problem arises when I include higher order term for example$$f(x) \approx f(x_0) + \frac{1}{2}(x- x_0)^2 f''(x_0) + \frac{1}{6}(x- x_0)^3 f'''(x_0)+\cdots.$$
$$I \approx \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\, e^{-f(x_0) - \frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)^2 f''(x_0)-\frac{1}{6}(x- x_0)^3 f'''(x_0)}= e^{-f(x_0)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\, e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)^2 f''(x_0)-\frac{1}{6}(x- x_0)^3 f'''(x_0)}.$$
Howsoever $f'''(x_0)$ is small compared to $f''(x_0)$ but at very large $x$ it will be going to dominate for example following plot is for $e^{-x^2+.005x^3}$ [image]
Infact including higher order odd power term will result in blowing up the integral. What is going wrong here? Is it because we're doing asymptotic analysis so we're bound to get diverging term in the result?

Comment: The approximation is only valid near the minimum. If you want to keep adding terms, it would be best to add in pairs up to the next even degree to do the integral. Adding only up to odd terms violates the hypothesis that $f$ has a global minimum.

Comment: It's true that $\int_0^\infty e^{\lambda (-x^2 + x^4 - x^6)} dx \sim \int_0^\epsilon e^{\lambda (-x^2 + x^4)} dx$ for a fixed $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$ and $\lambda \to \infty$, but you can't then extend the integration range to $[0, \infty)$. Instead, you can take $-x^2 + x^4 - x^6 = -\xi^2$ on $[0, \epsilon]$ and get a complete asymptotic series as $\sum_{k \geq 0} \int_0^\infty c_k \xi^k e^{-\lambda \xi^2} d\xi$.